# Rules for Diamond prob resolution or Multiple Inheritance in Java8

Tags: java, oop, java-8, diamond-problem, default-method

In Java a class can extend only one parent class but can implement multiple interfaces.
With
the introduction of default methods in Java 8 interface, there’s the possibility of a class inheriting more than one
method with the same signature by implementing  2 interfaces having the same default method 
This can create diamond problem as in C++

Example in below code the output  of

```
new C().hello(); is
```

> This is Second

```
   public interface First {

    default void hello(){
        System.out.println("This is First");
    }
}

 public interface Second extends First {

    default void hello(){
        System.out.println("This is Second");
    }
}

  public class MyClass implements First,Second {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass().hello();
    }
}
```

What are the resolution rules that Java uses to resolve Diamond Problem?
A simple answer like who takes precedence and when will be great.

Comment: Been wondering a lot. Great you raised this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Following are the rules to follow when a class inherits a method with the same signature from multiple places (another class or interface):

- Classes always win. A method declaration in the class or a superclass
  takes priority over any default method declaration.
- Otherwise, sub-interfaces win: the method with the same signature in the most specific defaultproviding
  interface is selected. (for example in your case method from Second interface should run as Second extends First).
- Finally, if the choice is still ambiguous, the class inheriting from multiple interfaces has to
  explicitly select which default method implementation to use by overriding it and calling the
  desired method explicitly.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.A very Precise answer with all the scenarios covered .Thanks! Rohit

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) that explains this pretty much in detail.

You have basically overridden your method from First interface and the most specific interface method is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet is no diamond problem as interface second extends interface first and overrides the method hello.

Without extending interface second the compiler throws an error

```
Duplicate default methods named hello with the parameters () and () are inherited from the types Second and First
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementing two Interfaces that declare the same default Method leads to an compilation error:

```
MyClass inherits unrelated defaults for sayHi() from types InterfaceA and InterfaceB
```

So there's no Diamond-Problem ;)

To solve this you can override the Method in the implementing Class and either implement it there or defer to the correct Interface.

In your case it would look like that (in case you want to use the method of Interface `First`):

```
 public class MyClass implements First,Second {
     public void hello() {
         First.super.hello();
     }
 }
```